# AngularJS Routing redirects to 404 page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following routing configuration:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode().enabled = true;
```

config file:

```
define(function (require) {
    "use strict";

    return ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/error/404');

        require('filePath')($stateProvider);
    }];
});
```

routing file:

```
define( function () {

    return function ( $stateProvider ) {

        return $stateProvider.state('hi', {
                                url:         '/',
                                templateUrl: 'common/hi.html',
                                controller:  'HiController'
                             })
                             .state('404', {
                                url:         '/error/404',
                                templateUrl: '404.html',
                             })
                             .state('somePage', {
                                url:         '/some/page',
                                templateUrl: 'page.html',
                                controller:  'HiController'
                             });
    };
});
```

and now, when I try to open e.g. `site.com/some/page` I'm being redirected to `site.com/error/404`. Why ?

Comment: Do you have <base href="/"> in the <head> of your HTML?

Comment: yes, I have it already